# JavaScript cannot access sibling method

Tags: javascript

Given the following how do i enable this to work correct?

```
return {

    methodA: function() {
        return methodB();
    },
    methodB: function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
}
```

Comment: `return this.methodB();`

Comment: that did not work for me

Comment: is there any more code around this or is that all of it.

Comment: @MartinGlennon It cannot be all of it, you can't have a return outside of a function

Comment: true but it may also be part of the problem

Answer (score 5):

You need to reference the context, via `this`.

```
var foo = {

    methodA: function() {
        return this.methodB(); //context
    },
    methodB: function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
}

foo.methodA(); //alerts "hi"
```

Comment: As long as you call it like `foo.methodA()`, just a warning so the OP knows to avoid doing `var func = foo.methodA` and calls `func()`. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37072507/227299) for a safer alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are returning from a module like function. The safe way is not to use `this`, it is to keep a reference to the object so that it won't matter how the function is called.

```
function getObj() {
  var obj = {
    methodA: function() {
      return obj.methodB();
    },
    methodB: function() {
        alert("hi");
    }
  };
  return obj;
}

var myObj = getObj();

// Works
myObj.methodA();
// Works but would not work if you were using `this` as suggested by Utkanos.
someDomElement.addEventListener('click', myObj.methodA);
```